# C++ need help figuring out word count in function. (Ex. Hello World = 2)

Tags: c++, function

I'm figuring out the algorithm on this function and it keeps crashing at runtime, here's the code snippet:

```
int wordCounter(char usStr[]) {
    int index= 0, punct= 0;

    while(usStr[index]!= '\0') //If it's not the end of the sentence
        if(usStr[index]== ' ') //If it finds a space
            index++;

    while(usStr[index]== '\0') //If it's the end of the sentence.
        punct++;
    int allChar= punct+ index;

    return allChar;
}
```

I shall post the full program if need arises, but for now I need someone to help me crack down the source of the problem.

UPDATE: Here's my int main. Assume numWords is a function that accepts a string class object as its argument and asks the user for input:

```
int main()
{
string userVal;
    numWords(userVal);
    char *conStr= new char[' ']; //I'm very doubtful and worried about the contents insing the [].
    strcpy(conStr, userVal.c_str()); //String converted to a C-string.
    int fin= wordCounter(conStr);
    cout<< "The number of words in the sentence is "<< fin<< "."<< endl;
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format your post properly.

Comment: So you only increment `index` if the character is a space? That doesn't look right...

Comment: First off, don't use character arrays.  Secondly use `std::string`, especially `cin >> string`.

Comment: What can I do to improve this? I have tried so many combos on making this work. My objective is to make a function that if I type: " I love pepperoni pizza", it returns the number 4.

Comment: Single step through your code with a *debugger* (preferred) or pen and paper (ancient technique).  *Watch* the values of the variables.  This will give you good information on how your program behaves.

Comment: No. This isn't a helpdesk or mentoring room.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have no idea what you're really asking for, I think you should have a condition to end your 1st `while()` loop to adjust at beginning of words:

```
int wordCounter(char usStr[]) {
    int index= 0, punct= 0;

    while(usStr[index]!= '\0') {  // <<< Use effin' braces
        if(usStr[index]== ' ') { // <<< Use effin' braces
            index++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // index points to a non ' ' character or '\0' here
    // No idea, what you're trying to achieve with the following lines
    // of code. 

    while(usStr[index] == '\0') { // If it's the end of the sentence ...
                                  // ... this part loops forever!
        punct++;
    }

    int allChar = punct + index;

    return allChar;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please guide me as to why it did this? I thought that by approaching the '\0' it was going to stop and count the word after a space or the '\0' of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
                int wordCounter(char usStr[]) {
        int index= sizeof(usStr);
        int result = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<index; i++){
            if(usStr[index]== ' ')
                   result++;
            }//end of the loop

        return result+1;

        } //try this one.
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Can you tell me as to why the while loop that I created doesn't count the spaces? It keeps giving me 0 for a reason that I do not understand.

Comment: if it keeps giving you 0. so the reason why get 0 is something is in the array wrong. i just convert while loop to for loop. try this one. let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: When I used `int index= usStr.length;`, compiler replied: "error: request for  member 'length' in 'usStr', which is of non-class type 'char*'.

Comment: sorry my bad. replace int index= usStr.length; with >>  int index = sizeof(usStr);

Answer (score 0):

Simple array way:

```
int wordCounter(char usStr[]) 
{
    int wordcount = 0;
    int charcount = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (usStr[index] != '\0')
    { 
        if (usStr[index] == ' ')
        {
            if (charcount)
            { //only count non-empty tokens
                wordcount++;
                charcount = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            charcount++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    if (charcount)
    {  // get last word, if any.
         wordcount++;
    }
    return wordcount;
}
```

Simple C++ way:

```
int wordCounter(char usStr[]) 
{
    int wordcount = 0;
    std::stringstream stream(usStr);
    std::string temp;
    while (stream >> temp)
    { // got a token
        wordcount++;
    }
    return wordcount;
}
```

Breakdown of what went wrong:

```
while(usStr[index]!= '\0') //good
    if(usStr[index]== ' ') //good
        index++; //bad
```

Lets look at a simple case "Hi!"

Iteration 1:
index = 0, usStr[index] = H

```
while(usStr[index]!= '\0')
```

H != '\0', enter

```
    if(usStr[index]== ' ') //good
```

H != ' ', do not enter. Do not increment index

Iteration 2:
index = 0, usStr[index] = H

```
while(usStr[index]!= '\0')
```

H != '\0', enter

```
    if(usStr[index]== ' ') //good
```

H != ' ', do not enter. Do not increment index

Iteration 3:
index = 0, usStr[index] = H

```
while(usStr[index]!= '\0')
```

H != '\0', enter

```
    if(usStr[index]== ' ') //good
```

H != ' ', do not enter. Do not increment index

See the problem yet? If not, I can cut and past all night. Rather get some food and sleep, though.

Comment: Thank you. I will post my full program and then could you tell me what can I do better to improve? I tried running it with the simple array, and I got 1. Also, where is `index` defined?

Comment: @ZeroTap Updated with a fix and an explanation of what went wrong in your posted version. Don't bother posting other code. Fix what you have here and ask a new question if you have problems elsewhere in your program. Stack too much into one question and it become incomprehensible. Basically, one question should be one question, though sometimes it spills over.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned, I'm a beginner. Sorry, I feel like I have to say that in case I'm totally wrong. :) Hopefully I won't have to say that for too long.

Anyways, I would do this in the simplest way I can come up with. Instead of a char array, I would just use a std::string. Here's a little function I made, which is derived from a function I made to split std::strings into substrings.

```
// split the string s into substrings and count the number of substrings
int count_substrings(const string& s)
{
    int count{ 0 };
    stringstream ss{ s };
    for (string buffer; ss >> buffer;)
        ++count;
    return count;
}
```

So what this does is it takes the string and stores it into a stringstream. Then the "ss >> buffer" will go through the characters in the string and when it hits whitespace, it'll store that substring into "buffer" and go into the for loop, which increments "count". It goes into the for loop each time it finds a substring, which is how it counts the number of substrings. Notice that "buffer" isn't actually being used anywhere. I'm sorry if this is a bad explanation of what's going on, but I'm trying. :) I hope this can help you a bit to understand what I'm doing. Please, if I'm wrong about something, correct me.

Then a very simple test of this function could be something like this:

```
cout << "Enter a string:\n";
string str;
getline(cin, str);

int count = count_substrings(str);
cout << "Number of substrings == " << count << '\n';
```